# Issue with make and Mac homebrew

Tags: macos, cmake, makefile, homebrew

I'm trying to use Homebrew on macOS and whenever it comes time to use make, it shows this error

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/milesacq/Library/Logs/Homebrew/webp/02.make:
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [libwebpdecode_la-io_dec.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libwebpdecode_la-alpha_dec.lo] Error 1
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libwebpdecode_la-vp8_dec.lo] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libwebpdecode_la-buffer_dec.lo] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libwebpdecode_la-quant_dec.lo] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libwebpdecode_la-idec_dec.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libwebpdecode_la-tree_dec.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I've tried "brew clean", "brew update", "brew upgrade", deleting and reinstalling make and the rest of the developer tools, and even deleting the Homebrew/webp folder in case something was wrong with the makefile itself

Any insights would be appreciated

EDIT: This seems to be caused by missing header files cstddef.h, string.h and SDL.h, how do I fix this? I have the latest version of the developer tools and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling

Comment: Are you sure CMake is relevant here? Make and CMake are 2 different programs. Not sure if homebrew uses cmake internally, but the output does not indicate the use of cmake. Furthermore the output indicates that it just printed the last 15 lines of the log (`Last 15 lines from /Users/milesacq/Library/Logs/Homebrew/webp/02.make`). Try checking, if the log file is still there and if it contains the reasong for the error instead of just the fact that there were errors.

Comment: It looks like `brew` is trying to build the requested package (libwebp?) from source and the build is failing.  If so the real errors are further back in the log -- those shown are just `make` saying that something has gone wrong and it's bailing.

Comment: "I'm trying to use Homebrew on macOS and whenever it comes time to use make" - I would hardly imagine what that means. Do you build and install a **specific project** using brew? Please, add to the question post the **exact command** you are running.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Any command that requires the use of a makefile. This specific example was the error after I tried to install Google Tesseract OCR and it tried to update its dependencies

Comment: @fabian thank you!! It says I'm missing header files for cstddef.h, string.h and SDL.h. Since I've tried updating and reinstalling the Xcode dev tools, what should I try next?

Comment: "Any command that requires the use of a makefile." - So, if you create a new directory with the only empty file `Makefile`, and run `make` from that directory, then you will get the error shown in the question post? I don't think so. Again, please be **specific** when describe the problem. BTW, in your [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70232113/issue-with-make-and-mac-homebrew?noredirect=1#comment124158366_70232113) you note about XCode. But nothing in your question post hints that you use XCode.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it turns out not to be an issue with make, but the issue comes up when I run make because it's attempting to compile a program that requires header files I don't have. I don't use Xcode, but macOS users install the standard developer programs (including make, gcc, clang, etc.) by downloading the Xcode developer tools

Comment: I'm facing this issue as well. I have Xcode installed, and I've opened Xcode and installed the additional stuff it prompts to install. Nevertheless, I'm still getting this same error. For me I noticed it specifically when attempting to upgrade `httpd`. @MilesAcq did you get this issue resolved?

Comment: I specifically started facing this issue after upgrading to macOS 12.3 (Monterey). It didn't occur on Big Sur.

Comment: This question is unanswerable. In essence it says *"somebody tried to do something, but we don't know what. Oh, and here's half the error message."*

Comment: I was able to work around the issue by forcing bottle installation. The dependency that was failing to install for me was `httpd` so I did `brew reinstall httpd --force-bottle` and then I was able to successfully do `brew upgrade`.